# How to bypass javax.validation.constraints.Min error in third party libraries?

Tags: java, guice, presto, javax.validation

When I load one third party class, I got exception regarding using javax.validation.constraints.Min on non-getter method. I don't care about that method, I am wondering how to turn off the checking, just let me use the rest of the function as is?

```
public com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.FeaturesConfig com.facebook.presto.sql.analyzer.FeaturesConfig.setConcurrentLifespansPerTask(int)] annotation @javax.validation.constraints.Min(message="{javax.validation.constraints.Min.message}", payload={}, groups={}, value=0) should be placed on a getter
```

The checking is from:
io.airlift.bootstrap when it is used with Guice

```
at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:543)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:159)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
at io.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:262)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried Trino, formerly known as Presto SQL? https://github.com/trinodb/trino

Comment: not yet, I am dealing with some legacy system, would like to make existing code work without big change. But I will try that if current path does not work. Thanks